# How to host a PDF on a Wix website using a SEO-optimised path?

Tags: seo, pdf, clean-urls, wix

I just created my first website with Wix. I want to add a PDF file to it.
Wix suggests to upload the file to the Wix and then add a button/icon for users to open. The problem is, the path to this file is a random sequence of characters (therefore non SEO-optimised) and [not changable](https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-customizing-document-file-names).

I have seen suggested as solution to host the file on a different platforms like Google Drive.
My doubts about his solution:

- Will having an external hosting site impact the traffic to my website?
- I want my website to look as professional as possible. Is it common to find professional websites using this Google Drive trick?

Maybe it would be OK if the hosting site was still part of my professional sphere, like my company's LinkedIn?

Could you suggest a way in which I can have a SEO-optimised path like:
`https://example.com/documents/my-document.pdf`
without losing respectability or traffic to my website?

Comment: My advice would be not to use Wix or other host with an integrated website building tool such as Google Sites.   I'm not sure if you can solve this problem with Wix, but that isn't the biggest problem.   It is very hard to migrate a site off Wix once you outgrow Wix or it no longer meets your requirements.  Pretty much the only way is copying and pasting your content one page at a time.  Because Wix is heavily JavaScript based, you probably won't even be able to find a crawler to scrape your own content off your site.

Comment: The Google Drive trick won't solve your path name issue since it will also generate a random directory name. I would just quit Wix as suggested by @StephenOstermiller or use it as it is because the impact of the file path is minimal if compared to domain or file name